# How to use dependency to mock data. MVC5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC5 and i am trying to work on 'search' functionality. my aim is get data from a dataservice.(that is, i enter data into a form and hit the search button, if theres a record it displays data).

I have created a dependency to mock the data(dummy data). How do i wire up my code to the contoller to achieve my purpose?. Please advice Thank you.

Heres my controller and my mock:

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISearchResultsService _resultsService;

    public SearchController() : this(DependencyFactory.NewResultsService())
    {         

    }

    public SearchController(ISearchResultsService resultsService)
    {
        _resultsService = resultsService;
    }

    // GET:Search
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Search/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Search/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Search/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return();
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    //[HttpPost]
    //public ActionResult Index(SearchCriteria data)
    //{
    //    var data = this._resultsService.FindClaims(data);
    //    return View(data);
    //}

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();


    }

    // GET: Search/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Search/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add update logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    // GET: Search/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Search/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add delete logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}

public static class DependencyFactory
{
    public static ISearchResultsService NewResultsService()
    {
        return new MockSearchResultsService();
    }
}

public interface ISearchResultsService
{
    List<Person> FindClaims(string firstName, string lastName);
}

public class MockSearchResultsService : ISearchResultsService
{
    public List<Person> FindClaims(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        return new List<Person>(new []{new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"}});//throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use some **IoC container** like http://autofac.org. You can configure your container and register your service like this way:

```
builder.RegisterType<MockSearchResultsService>().As<ISearchResultsService>()
```

All your dependencies will be automatically resolved:

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISearchResultsService _resultsService;

    public SearchController(ISearchResultsService resultsService)
    {         
        _resultsService = resultsService;
    }
}
```

Note that there is many IoC containers you can use. Try to search more about **AutoFac**, **Ninject** or **Castle Windsor**.